# Ubuntu: integrated GPU allocates too much VRAM for itself

Tags: ubuntu, memory, bios, integrated-graphics

I'm having a problem. Despite I have set VRAM to be exactly 32 megabytes in BIOS, Ubuntu still allocates 256 MB for it, as shown on pictures below.
My hardware: Asus P8B75-M LX motherboard with latest BIOS on it with Intel Pentium g630 CPU. Running Ubuntu server 18.04

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Just to test if it's a hardware or software problem, I have quickly installed Windows just to test things out. Windows takes only 100 MB RAM, which is still greater than 32 MB I have set, but it is better, as shown on picture below:

[image: Image 4]

I would really like to free up some RAM.

Comment: What you’re setting in the BIOS is the (starting) amount of shared memory. It’s not related to the mapped memory you’re looking at on Linux. // Use a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: well I mean it's a problem that needs a solution...